# SQL Select Data between two values

Tags: sql, select, between

Does someone know, how to select all data

```
   between (AE = "A" AND AE = "E") 
OR between (AE = "A" AND AE = "B")  
OR  between (AE = "B" AND AE = "E")
```

Table is sorted by IPID and than by measurement_time

please look at the pic attached.

Thanks!!

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ6ta.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what those conditions are supposed to mean.  Only the first is needed, logically.

Comment: there are also Bs in the data set. i just like to select the rows between an A and an E (or B) and put them in a new table

Comment: so like: when AE is A: take all lines after (in time) until AE is E and put them in a new table

Comment: What's your DBMS, does it support Windowed Aggregates, `last_value`?

Comment: I am not sure.. I guess its Oracle. I work with SAS Enterprise Guide and I tried with the Lag() funktion what is, i guess, the same like last_value.. 
But it dint work.

Comment: @M.Lat . . . I think you should ask another question.  Include sample data, desired results, *and an explanation of what you want to accomplish*.

Answer (score 0):

You second and third  between is unuseful because the first condition cover the 
 result for the two others   anyway the righ sintax should be

```
  select * from my_table 
  where   (AE between  "A" AND  "E") 
      OR  (AE between  "A" AND  "B")  
      OR  (AE between  "B" AND  "E")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to deal with other values or if A/B/E might repeat, but a similar logic should work: Fill empty rows with the previous A/B/E character and then filter.

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT t.*,
      Last_Value(CASE WHEN AE IN ('A', 'B', 'E' THEN AE END IGNORE NULLS)
      Over (PARTITION BY IPID
            ORDER BY measurement_time
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS lv
   FROM tab t
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE lv IN ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

TomKari from sas.com forum found a solution in data step.

thanks dnoeth and scaisEdge for you help!!

Have have a nice day!!

```
data SetSwitch;
    retain KeepSwitch 0;
    set Have;

    if AE = "A" then KeepSwitch = 1;
    else if AE = "E" then KeepSwitch = 0;
    else if AE = "B" & KeepSwitch = 1 then KeepSwitch = 0;
    else if AE = "B" & KeepSwitch = 0 then KeepSwitch = 1;
run;

data SetVar;
    set SetSwitch;

    if KeepSwitch = 1 then if AE = " " then AE = lag(AE);
run;

data Want;
    set SetVar;

    if AE ^= " " then output;
run;
```